# Msbuild packaging Issue

Tags: msdeploy, msbuild-4.0

Currently I am working on a mvc3 project and I use msbuild command line tool to do the packaging.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>msbuild MVC-Client.csproj /t:package /P:Configuration=staging
```

In my machine this command executes successfully and it creates a deploy-able package.And in deploy bat file it has following web deployment configs.

```
MSDeployPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\**Microsoft Web Deploy V2**\"
```

And but when I am trying to run same msbuild command in my build server machine(jenkings server) it creates a different bat file with following web deployment configs.

```
set MSDeployPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\"
```

In both machines I use same version of msbuild. And also i have both msdeply1 and msdeploy2 installed in those machines. What could be the reason for this ? I am using Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1 version of msbuild.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have SP1 of VS2010 installed on your build server? It looks like you may not. For your case you should install one of the bundles at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/15/visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx.

Comment: you are correct. We need to install SP1 of VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that install web deploy v1 after Web deploy v2, try to reinstall Web Deploy v2 on your build server.